# duda Z-index o como superposiciones de un elemento

Tags: javascript, css

**Ejemplo de como quiero que quede**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de que manera puedo lograr posicionar la caja que esta atras , porque por ejemplo estaba intentandolo con Z-index pero el resultado no me dio igual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como yo lo tengo como podrán observar se nota que si esta atras el cuadro login pero el problema es que esta muy visible se nota mucho lo que hay en el cuadro login

```
cuadro Register
.Box{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  transform: translateX(25rem)translateY(15rem);
  width: 520px;
  height: 390px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

cuadro Login
.Box-2{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  transform: translateX(38rem)translateY(19rem);
  width: 520px;
  height: 390px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Usa blur: `filter: blur(4px);`, esto desenfocara el contenido del fondo pero tendra la misma opacidad.

Comment: tambien pense en eso , pero eso lo dejaría igual solo mas desenfocado

Comment: Entonces quitale la transprencia al fono y hazlo con opacidad, haz una sola clase para los dos cuadros y añade una clase .active para manejar cuando el box este en frente o no, si quieres te hago una respuesta.

Comment: En si ¿cuál es la duda?

Comment: mi duda era acerca del z-index y que otras propiedades podia complementarlas para poder obtener el resultado que queria del ejemplo que muestre arriba , @DєηyηCrawford amigo lo del opacity me funciono bien si hay otra forma aparte del opacity tambien puedes ponerla para ver todas las opciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de como podrías usar el z-index. Pero para que se veo mas chiquito y por detras, agregas sombreado, opacidad al elemento de por detras y escala.

**HTML**

```
<div class="w-40 vh-50 position-relative">
    <div class="w-100 h-100 bg-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center block-content primary">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary primary">Boton</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 h-100 bg-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center block-content secondary active">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary secondary">Boton</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
.block-content {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.primary {
    z-index: 2;
}
.secondary {
    z-index: 1;
}
.secondary.active {
    left: 20%;
    transform: scale(.8);
    opacity: .8;
}
</style>
```

Si te sientes perdido con tantas clases, es por que yo he usado Bootstrap aquí, para hacerlo mas rápido.